# PHP JSON object nested loop data syntax

Tags: php, json, object, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through some JSON data and pull out specific values.  Here is the JSON data and the partially working code.

```
$jsondata = '
[
  {
  "id" : "421356",
  "trip_update" : {
    "trip" : {
      "trip_id" : "421356",
      "start_time" : "12:05:00",
      "start_date" : "20130926",
      "route_id" : "15"
    },
    "stop_time_update" : {
       "stop_sequence" :70,
      "departure" : {
        "delay" : 240,
        "time" : 1380215057
      },
      "stop_id" : "6090"
    },
    "stop_time_update" : {
       "stop_sequence" :71,
      "departure" : {
        "delay" : 240,
        "time" : 1380215075
      },
      "stop_id" : "6095"
    }
  }
}]';
$result = json_decode($jsondata);

foreach($result as $value) {
  echo "trip_id: ".$value->trip_update->trip->trip_id;
  if (gettype($value->trip_update ) == "object") {
    foreach($value->trip_update as $item) {
       echo " - stop_sequence: ".$item->stop_sequence;
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the first level of data under 'trip_update->trip'.  But there can be any number of 'stop_time_update' data within 'trip_update' as well.  Since this data relates to the trip_update data, I need to loop through it and correlate it.

The end goal is to save this data to a database (not shown in the code), so for clarity, this would be the simplified 2 rows of DB data I would like to save in this example:

```
trip_id,stop_sequence
421356,70
421356,71
```

There can be any number of stop_sequences in the source data.

Here is an interactive link to the code for you to edit or mess with:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f21ca8928da7de3e9fb351edb075d0a446906937

Comment: Try [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.org), although it is valid JSON, second occurrence of `stop_time_update` is removed (or rather first if overwritten with second one), it object property and can not be defined twice. It should be an array containing two objects

Comment: I know it validates, as i mentioned it in my comment. Point is, that it  is badly structured and you should mention it to the provider of this JSON.

Comment: It might validates, but you don't have a proper array structure `[]` around the repeated elements. Thus you are losing data on `json_decode()` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi maybe you can change the name.

```
function next_update($coincidencias){
$replace=$coincidencias[0].$GLOBALS["json_stop_time_update"]++;
return $replace;
}
$result= preg_replace_callback("/stop_time_update/","next_update",$jsondata);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: Holy cow that was helpful.  I was able to rename all of those and then loop through them and extract the data from the new object.  Nice.  This is definitely one solution - fix the bad JSON data.  Let me look at the others before I mark this.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better results if you write your own parser or use a stream-parser with callbacks. Here's a [PHP implementation](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser) of such a parser that works with callbacks. So instead of reading the whole JSON data into memory, the parser will read the data in chunks and notify your "listener-class" whenever a new object starts or a property was read in etc. By doing this, you should get separate callback events for each `stop_time_update` property instead of just one value in the parsed array.

Very similar to what [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) is for XML.

Comment: Hey that's a really useful parser.  I think it would work, and maybe I'll use it later.  But for now Erick's solution works.

Answer (score 1):

You should rework your JSON - you have multiple keys with the same name, try to do `print_r($result)` to see what I am talking about - PHP will override the "stop_time_update" key time after time and you will be able to access only the last entry. Instead, you should organize your JSON like that:

```
[
  {
  "id" : "421356",
  "trip_update" : {
    "trip" : {
      "trip_id" : "421356",
      "start_time" : "12:05:00",
      "start_date" : "20130926",
      "route_id" : "15"
    },
    "stop_time_update" : [{
       "stop_sequence" :70,
      "departure" : {
        "delay" : 240,
        "time" : 1380215057
      },
      "stop_id" : "6090"
    }, {
       "stop_sequence" :71,
      "departure" : {
        "delay" : 240,
        "time" : 1380215075
      },
      "stop_id" : "6095"
    }]
  }
}]
```

then you will be able to iterate through your data like this:

```
foreach($result[0]->trip_update->stop_time_update as $update)
{
     $time = $update->departure->time;
     ...
}
```

If you cannot change the data structure, then what probably could help you is a PULL parser - one that does not return parsed data structure, but allows you to use a data stream instead - this way you could iterate over each node. The only one I managed to find is an extension to PHP:

https://github.com/shevron/ext-jsonreader

Check the usage section.

Comment: Thanks but I have no control over the JSON. It comes from an external source.  I suppose I could do some regex replacing to change the first instance of stop_time_update one way and subsequent ones in the same trip_update another way.  That seems like it might not work though, but if you could whip up an example I could try it with the real file.  I'm hoping for another way though.

Comment: I do see your point though. print_r($result) shows that only the last stop_time_update data is saved in the object.

Comment: That's exactly my point - if your JSON contains duplicate keys, you will only have access to the last provided value; I am not aware of a JSON parsing method that would handle that differently

Comment: Yes you are right.  I'll have to adjust the JSON in order for it to parse correctly because of the duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

This `JSON` response is invalid because it contains duplicate keys but `JSON` doesn't `allow duplicate keys`.

You should contact the service you're trying to request this response from.

If you have a valid `JSON` response then you can decode it using the `json_decode` function which returns an object or an array (depends on the second parameter);

You cannot use a `JSON parser` for this as it will always overwrite the first element due to the same keys. The only proper solution would be asking whoever creates that "JSON" to fix his code to either use an array or an object with unique keys.

Another option is to write your own decoder function for parse it

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Writing a parse would work, or using an existing one.  Since this is for a tech demo I've used Erick's solution since it's quicker to implement.